# vcvarsall - Using 64bit compiler and then switching back to 32bit for seperate build

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, batch-file, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I'm using vcvarsall to switch to x64 compile tools for VS2010, as I run into memory issues with a certain build. However I'd like to also switch BACK to x86 tools for regular builds.

Currently I have a batch file that looks like this:

```
CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x64
set _IsNativeEnvironment=true

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv" "C:\Development\projectx.sln" /build "Debug|x64"

CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
set _IsNativeEnvironment=true

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv" "C:\Development\projectx.sln" /build "Debug|x86"
```

This works for the first build, but the second will still launch 64bit compiler/linker - which gives errors occasionally (why I need to use 32 for it).
In testing I found that it will work only if I open a *new command line* after running the x86 vcvarsall.bat - how can I mimic this in a batch file?

Comment: Yeah, that cannot work.  These bat files were written to setup an environment from scratch, they don't carefully remove any values that might have been added by another invocation of the .bat file.  You'll need to start using msbuild.exe if you want to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use [setlocal](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) and [endlocal](http://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html)

```
setlocal
CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x64
set _IsNativeEnvironment=true

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv" "C:\Development\projectx.sln" /build "Debug|x64"
endlocal

setlocal
CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
set _IsNativeEnvironment=true

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv" "C:\Development\projectx.sln" /build "Debug|x86"
endlocal
```